# from which she had failed to return home

Tags: sentence-construction

I found one sentence a bit hard to understand while reading a prose written by a Chinese author; if I rewrite it into "which she had failed to return from," the word  **home** then seems unnecessary. I can sense there is a difference between *from which she had failed to return* and *from which she had failed to return home*, but I'm still confused, please tell me if there's any other way to rewrite this line?

Here's a quote:

> This little manoeuvre instantly recalled to my mind’s eye the image of
> my maternal grandmother doing so for me, for she had been doing so for
> me from my childhood years until a little before she fell grievously
> sick and was sent into the hospital to go through a tormenting and
> lonely sojourn, *from which she had failed to return home*.

Comment: We commonly speak of people going or coming **home** from hospital.

Comment: And even in situations not involving hospitalization:  **I will pick up the mail at the post office when we return home from our visit.**  We used to call **home** an adverb when used in that manner, but my hunch is that it's probably regarded as a preposition or adposition in modern grammars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> from which she had failed to return home

This expression has a double meaning, and the author had meant both of those meanings, and that's why it was used.

The expression reveals:

- whether she regained her health; whether she healed or not,
- whether she returned into our lives (into our family home, into our community), or not.

When she failed to do that, it means that

- not only she lost her life, but importantly,
- we, the rest of us, the family, had also lost her.

  - Actually, the narrative is almost putting a greater emphasis on our perspective of loss then on hers.

    - Because, in the end, it's us who remain here and remain to have any conscious perspective, any perception of this reality from which she is now irrevocably missing — unlike her, who had left all that capacity for suffering behind.

In my interpretation, that's what that single word, "home" does, in that sentence.

---

Additionally:

This excercise seems to demonstrate that *home* is more than mere shelter.

*Home* —especially in high literature— appears to imply an expectation of human community.